# click function for each class item

Tags: javascript

I have a class `hardware` that, when clicked, I would like to change the background color upon hitting my `run` function. However, my click sets them all to the same color at once.

How would I distinguish between each `hardware` with their respective click event?

```js
function run(){
var selector = document.getElementsByClassName('hardware');
for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; i++){
  var index = selector[i];
  selector[i].style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
}

}
```

```html
    <section onclick="run()" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is one</section>
    <section onclick="run()" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is two</section>
    <section onclick="run()" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is three</section>
    <section onclick="run()" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is four</section>
    <section onclick="run()" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is five</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the element to the function using `run(this)`, then set the color only for that element:

```js
function run(el){
  el.style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";

}
```

```html
<section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is one</section>
    <section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is two</section>
    <section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is three</section>
    <section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is four</section>
    <section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is five</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function run(selector){
  selector.style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
}

<section onclick="run(this)" class="hardware">some text, nth-child is one</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```js
function run(event){
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "hotpink";
}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName("hardware"),
    function (el){
      el.onclick = run;
    }
);
```

```html
<section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is one</section>
<section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is two</section>
<section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is three</section>
<section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is four</section>
<section class="hardware">some text, nth-child is five</section>
```